# How to mirror an HTML page on web and mobile in realtime

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a project where i can mirror text written on a web page in a browser to reflect in a mobile version on the same page.

I thought i'll use query params to create a chat room like scenario wherein he can key in a message on a web browser in a PC and that will reflect on the same chat room in the browser but it's not working.

Any idea on how i can accomplish that?

Comment: [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/) would be appropriate for a realtime system. Have a look at it.

Comment: Have a server managing chat messages and show them accordingly on all clients.

Comment: Like @AhsN  , said NodeJs is a good server side backend for this, and then use `socket.io`,. really easy.